# Angular Checkbox Not Checked on First Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have an issue with a checkbox instead of an ng-repeat...

Here is the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="education in subject.Educations">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="education.Selected" id="verify_edu_{{$index}}" />{{education.Selected}}</td>
    <td>{{education.School}}</td>
    <td>{{education.Degree}}</td>
    <td>{{education.Major}}</td>
    <td>{{education.Certification}}</td>
</tr>
```

everyone outputs correctly, in terms of the school/degree/ etc etc. However, upon clicking the checkbox to check it, the checkbox does not reflect as checked, it's not until the 2nd click that the checkbox reflects as checked...

HOWEVER... the model does show the "education.Selected = true" on the FIRST click, even though the checkbox is not checked.

I have no idea why this is outputting... here are the screenshots of the checkbox through the process:

**Step One - Nothing clicked, everything outputs correctly**

[image]

**Step Two - Clicked to check box, box does NOT check, but value outputs as if box was checked with true value**

[image]

**Step Three - Clicked second time to check box, box DOES check, value remains the same as true**

[image]

Also - no matter how many times i click, it always takes two clicks for the checkbox to actually show a "checked" state - even though the model binded "education.Selected" shows true in both instances.

**Tested plain checkbox**
I put a plain, non binded checkbox next to the binded checkbox, the normal checkbox works fine. Just an FYI

**Browsers**
I tested in all major browsers - ie/firefox/chrome - same result across the board.

**One more note...**
There is another ng-repeater on the page, for work histories (not educations) - that outputs nearly identical, however the checkbox on it works fine.

Comment: Try `ng-checked="education.Selected"`

Comment: I did try that earlier w/ no luck

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr replicating the issue?

Comment: I've created a slightly-simplified example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtUzSSHHrmcRabQmnrdA) and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: 99823 What is your navigator, and version? The code from @SteveGreatrex works on Firefox and IE, with no problems.

Comment: It's Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m - that plunkr works for me also - i'm trying to figure out why, as that plunkr isn't much different than my code at all... very weird.

Comment: Another difference, i'm loading the educations from an API call, not sure if that makes a difference. This is driving me insane though. so weird....

Comment: I would suggest making the smallest possible plunkr that reproduces your issue and share it here. Try removing small parts of your real code until it works!

Comment: It suddenly started working yesterday with absolutely no code change from me. I am utterly baffled and quite disappointed that I couldn't pin point the problem before it decided to randomly work again... so weird...

Comment: Also having this issue, not sure why